# Special Table Spacing in Latex

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table in which I display a row with say "x" and in the following row below "x" I display the standard error of "x". However, I want those two rows to be close to each other and also to be a separated from the preceding and subsequent row-pairs.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}

            &        Mod1   &        Mod2   &        Mod3   &        Mod4   \\

            &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   \\


excess      &       0.042***&       0.039***&       0.040***&       0.037*** \\
            &    (0.0100)   &    (0.0096)   &    (0.0055)   &    (0.0054)   \\

ex2         &      -0.000*  &      -0.000*  &      -0.000***&      -0.000***\\
            &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0000)   &    (0.0000)   \\

giniv       &       0.956   &               &       0.979   &               \\
            &    (0.6618)   &               &    (0.5101)   &               \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `\\[.5\normalbaselineskip]` to insert a larger gap between entries..

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

### Insert a blank line

The simplest is to insert a blank line into your table in the place where you want to increase the spacing:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}

            &        Mod1   &        Mod2   &        Mod3   &        Mod4   \\
            &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   \\

            &               &               &               &               \\
excess      &       0.042***&       0.039***&       0.040***&       0.037***\\
            &    (0.0100)   &    (0.0096)   &    (0.0055)   &    (0.0054)   \\

            &               &               &               &               \\
ex2         &      -0.000*  &      -0.000*  &      -0.000***&      -0.000***\\
            &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0000)   &    (0.0000)   \\

            &               &               &               &               \\
giniv       &       0.956   &               &       0.979   &               \\
            &    (0.6618)   &               &    (0.5101)   &               \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

### Line spacing

Now, you may consider the space between the lines giving the value of x and its standard error excessive. You can shrink the overall line spacing in your table by setting, for instance `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}` before `\begin{tabular}`.

### Fine-tuning

Finally, you can fine-tune the vertical space of your tables by inserting `\vphantom`. `\vphantom{\LARGE X}` will not produce an output other than inserting a vertical phantom space of an uppercase X in the size of a `\LARGE` font.

```
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}

            &        Mod1   &        Mod2   &        Mod3   &        Mod4   \\
            &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   &        b/se   \\

excess      &       0.042***&       0.039***&       0.040***&\vphantom{\LARGE X} 0.037***\\
            &    (0.0100)   &    (0.0096)   &    (0.0055)   &    (0.0054)   \\

ex2         &      -0.000*  &      -0.000*  &      -0.000***&\vphantom{\LARGE X}-0.000***\\
            &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0000)   &    (0.0000)   \\

giniv       &       0.956   &               &       0.979   &\vphantom{\LARGE X}         \\
            &    (0.6618)   &               &    (0.5101)   &               \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that adding a little bit of vertical whitespace after every second numeric row -- so that information about coefficient estimates and standard errors is grouped visually -- is only one of several layout challenges you face. Three additional objectives, in my opinion, should be (i) aligning the numbers on their decimal points, (ii) typesetting the numbers in math mode so that negative numbers get a typographically correct minus signs rather than a simple dashes, and (iii) using horizontal lines judiciously to further improve the readability of the table.

The first two objectives can be met with the [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package, and the third with the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. The `booktabs` package also provides the macro `\addlinespace`, with which one can achieve your stated objective (though not automatically) of getting a bit more space after selected rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} % define a "decimal" column type
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % a handy shortcut macro
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\emph{Before}
\begin{table}[h!] % "[h!]" just for this example 
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
& Mod1   & Mod2   & Mod3   & Mod4   \\
& b/se   & b/se   & b/se   & b/se   \\
excess   & 0.042***& 0.039***& 0.040***& 0.037*** \\
&    (0.0100)   &    (0.0096)   &    (0.0055)   &    (0.0054)   \\
ex2      & -0.000*  & -0.000*  & -0.000***& -0.000***\\
&    (0.0001)   &    (0.0001)   &    (0.0000)   &    (0.0000)   \\
giniv   & 0.956   &   & 0.979   &   \\
&    (0.6618)   &   &    (0.5101)   &   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\emph{After}
\begin{table}[h!] % "[h!]" just for this example 
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule
& \mc{Mod1} & \mc{Mod2} & \mc{Mod3} & \mc{Mod4} \\
& \mc{b/se} & \mc{b/se} & \mc{b/se} & \mc{b/se} \\
\midrule
excess & 0.042^{***} & 0.039^{***} & 0.040^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\
       & (0.0100)    & (0.0096)    & (0.0055)    & (0.0054)    \\
\addlinespace
ex2    & -0.000^{*}  & -0.000^{*}  & -0.000^{***}& -0.000^{***}\\
       & (0.0001)    & (0.0001)    & (0.0000)    & (0.0000)    \\
\addlinespace
giniv  &  0.956   & &  0.979   & \\
       & (0.6618) & & (0.5101) & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```